# Why didn't Haman just kill Mordechai?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther

Why didn't Haman just kill Mordechai?

Assuming he was a high official, didn't he have the authority to kill someone that disrespected him?

In other words, since Mordechai violated the King's decree to bow down to Haman, why didn't he just kill him right away?

As it says in Esther 3:2

ב וְכָל־עַבְדֵ֨י הַמֶּ֜לֶךְ אֲשֶׁר־בְּשַׁ֣עַר הַמֶּ֗לֶךְ כֹּֽרְעִ֤ים וּמִֽשְׁתַּֽחֲוִים֙ לְהָמָ֔ן **כִּי־כֵ֖ן צִוָּה־ל֣וֹ הַמֶּ֑לֶךְ** וּמָ֨רְדֳּכַ֔י לֹ֥א יִכְרַ֖ע וְלֹ֥א יִֽשְׁתַּֽחֲוֶֽה

2 And all the king's servants who were in the king's gate would kneel and prostrate themselves before Haman, **for so had the king commanded concerning him**, but Mordecai would neither kneel nor prostrate himself.

Comment: Mordechai was also an advisor to Achasveirosh ,so that would not be possible

Comment: Opposite https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80773/759

Comment: ויבז בעיניו לשלח יד במרדכי לבדו.... Isn't this the whole premise of the Megillah? Haman cooks up a plot to kill all the Jews just to get at Mordechai. Decides to just kill him, but when he goes to the king the king tells him to honor Mordechai in the street. He's rushed immediately to the Queen's party only to find out she's a Jew too and she gets the king to kill him to save herself. They can't undo the order but they can give the Jews the right to self defense and the Jews indeed successfully defend themselves and establish a holiday commemorating their success.

Comment: @DoubleAA From that phrase I don't understand why it was not good in his eyes to just kill Mordechai alone.  He thought that it was bad to just kill Mordechai, but what was the reason?