# Was Mordechai mekayem "מְכַשֵּׁפָה לֹא תְחַיֶּה"?

Tags: mitzvah, purim

Was Mordechai mekayem the mitzvah aseh of מְכַשֵּׁפָה לֹא תְחַיֶּה based off the understanding of the Ramban [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.22.17?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=he#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95) that it is a mitzvah Aseh to kill a sorcerer.

Using the understanding that Haman was a grand sorcerer (See [Here](https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Etz_Chaim%2C_Gate_of_The_New_Month%2C_Chanukah%2C_and_Purim.5.14?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%98%D7%90&with=Lexicon&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%A2%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A3%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%2C%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%A9%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%94%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94%2C%20%D7%95%D7%99%27%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%99%27%20%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA%2C) and [Here](https://www.sefaria.org/Bnei_Yissaschar%2C_Adar.1.10.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%93%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%A2%20%D7%94%D7%99%27%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A3%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C).)

looking from the Kedushas levi [Here](https://www.sefaria.org/Kedushat_Levi%2C_Exodus%2C_Homily_for_Purim.28?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%9B%D7%9F%20%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95) it seems that Mordechai hanged Haman himself.

would this mean that Mordechai was mekayem MItzvah Aseh D'oraysa of killing a sorcerer?

additionally, from [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.22.17?ven=Metsudah_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Tur_HaArokh%2C_Exodus.22.17&lang2=bi#:%7E:text=In%20our%20case%2C%20the%20wording%20of%20the%20Torah%20implies%20that%20all%20means%20of%20killing%20such%20a%20witch%20must%20be%20employed%20if%20it%20proves%20impossible%20to%20convict%20her%20by%20the%20normal%20legal%20processes%20and%20the%20stringent%20demands%20of%20testimony%20normally%20applied%20in%20prosecutions%20that%20can%20result%20in%20the%20death%20penalty) it can seem that there are times that a conviction by beis din is not necessary.

(I wonder how many individuals throughout Jewish history have been mekayam this mitzvah...)

Comment: Shimon Ben Shetach did https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Sanhedrin.45b.22.1?lang=he  it might be that the mitzvah is on jews not non jews though.

Comment: There is an argument whether a non Jew is forbidden to do Kishuf in Sanhedrin 59b - the Rambam does not mention it among their prohibitions

Comment: @שלום i dont see any machlokes in the gemara you mentioned, it states clearly that it applies to everyone. https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.60a.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:~:text=Whoever%20lies%20with%20an%20animal%2C%E2%80%9D%20including%20gentiles%2C%20is%20included%20in%20the%20command%3A%20%E2%80%9CYou%20shall%20not%20allow%20a%20witch%20to%20live.%E2%80%9D

Comment: I think the mitzvah is to do so based on a psak by beis din, so probably not. The mitzvah he did was protecting the Jews.

Comment: @N.T. Im curious how that would work, would a non jewish perosn suspected of sorcerery need to be brought into a beis din (presumably by force) and convicted in order for the mitzvah to be obligatory?

Comment: Of course, like almost anything else. Not necessarily brought in, but you would need valid testimony and a psak from the Beis Din.